# Running JUnit 4 tests (under Vintage execution engine) with JUnit 5 @Tag

Tags: junit, junit4, junit5, cucumber-junit

Currently, as far as I am aware, Cucumber supports being run on JUnit 5 through the vintage execution engine.

Suppose I have the following test runner:

```java
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber" },
                 features={ "src/test/resources" },
                 strict = true)
@Tag("ACCEPTANCE_TEST") 
public class TestRunner { }
```

If I run this with the tag expression defined as "ACCEPTANCE_TEST" in JUnit 5 it won't be picked up and run.

However, if I run it with the expression defined as a NOT (which would be true for the test class) e.g. "!UNIT_TEST" then it will be picked up and run.

How can I mix the JUnit 5 tag with a JUnit 4 test runner (such as the one above) so that it works for the positive match of a tag expression?

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR

You cannot.

### Still TLDR

You cannot, at least not without reimplementing most of what Cucumber's JUnit4 runner does.

### Long Story

To understand why, you have to grasp the differences of some terms:

- JUnit 4: A single module (jar file) containing the test writing API, the test executor, the API to run tests, and at least two different mechanisms to extend it (rules and runners).
- Cucumber JUnit4 runner: Cucumber's way to integrate with JUnit 4. Activated through `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)`
- JUnit 5: A platform to run different test engines that comes in a few modules and provides an API to be used by IDEs and build tools and an SPI to plug-in test engines
- Vintage: The test engine to use JUnit 4 within the JUnit 5 platform
- Jupiter: The new test engine that evolves in sync with the JUnit 5 platform and is maintained by the same team.

Here's the thing: The `@Tag` annotation is a Jupiter feature and cannot possibly work with Cucumber's JUnit 4 runner. The JUnit 5 way to use Cucumber is the Cucumber test engine: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/junit-platform-engine. AFAIU it has its own tagging mechanism and does not use `@Tag` because different test engines work side-by-side but do not share functionality.